# what would be the best approach to aligning the labels with their corresponding QlistWidgets

Tags: python, pyside2

I have a series of QlistWidgets and I have labels positioned above them. I do not know the best approach to aligning the labels so they are directly above the QlistWidgets they are titles for and having that alignment work for any monitor size. I am currently using a vertical layout with two horizontal layouts added, the first horizontal one has the title labels and the second has a series of QlistWidgets.

this is what I currently have:

[image]

and this is what I would like:

[image: ][2]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a QGridLayout:

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)

        name_lw = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        name_lw.addItems("Name1 Name2 Name3".split())

        c_ver_lw = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        c_ver_lw.addItems("1 1 6 1 1 1".split())

        l_ver_lw = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        l_ver_lw.addItems("2 6 6 6 2 2".split())

        entity_name_lw = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        entity_name_lw.addItems("Entity1 Entity2 Entity3".split())

        path_lw = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        path_lw.addItems("Path1 Path2 Path3".split())

        titles = ("Name", "C-ver", "L-ver", "Entity Name", "Path")
        lws = (name_lw, c_ver_lw, l_ver_lw, entity_name_lw, path_lw)

        for i, (title, lw) in enumerate(zip(titles, lws)):
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(title)
            grid_layout.addWidget(label, 0, i)
            grid_layout.addWidget(lw, 1, i)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]